# Android graphics , dynamic view

Tags: android

I am looking for help/resource that will help me in bringing up a image as follows in android view.

1. Image looks like x-y axis graph, with sawtooth waves along x-axis, this is a static image developed using certain tool.
2. I need help to make a line move, parallel to y-axis (red in color) that waits at origin(0,0) and starts moving along x axis until the sawtooth wave ends.

3.If you imagine this as image, there is a wave on x axis and a red line that moves across wave, which is the noise generated in android mobile.

Concern: How to overlap a static image (wave+x-y axis) with a dynamic image (red line) and make it move as the code runs. 
There is a timer that will generate the noise (mute/unmute microphone) and user gets to see it in screen when these interference occurs. 
I thank you for spending time to read my post. 
Please let me know if there are any redundant info , I will edit my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you subclass view you can draw whatever you want in the `onDraw()`.  You just need to use the provided `Canvas`.

Comment: Is there a suitable tutorial that will help me on this.

Comment: Yeah, just Google "java canvas drawing" and you'll see a bunch of them